# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'network' of undefined while trying to log image url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that will automatically download certain images from a website.  I tried to use the example from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network) this code:

```
 chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(function(request) {
     if (request.response.bodySize > 40*1024)
         chrome.experimental.devtools.console.addMessage(
         chrome.experimental.devtools.console.Severity.Warning,
         "Large image: " + request.request.url);
 });
```

This is my manifest.json

```
"name": "image downloader",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "potaot",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "testpopup.html"
  },
  "author":  "me",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches" : [ "http://www.free-pictures-photos.com/landscapes/*" ],
        "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"]
```

If anyone could help it would be hugely appreciated.
here is the contentscript.js:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Please paste more of your code and explain your problem a little more. The manifest file is unlikely to be the problem here.

Comment: The `chrome.devtools` API is only available to DevTools extensions. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools